# NSOperationQueue implementation for monotouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am using NSOperationQueue for uploading image in background and when image uploads it return url and this image url we are using for saving data.I am using this code but it is not waiting until Url get from first operation execution.

I want that postScrap will not execute unless and until PostScrapPicture method will not
execute,I am using OperationQueue.WaitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished(); for this but it is not executing.

First operation:

```
Action asyncUploadAction = () => {                  
    OperationQueue.AddOperation(()=>{
    PostScrapPicture (ownerUserId,scrapImage,serviceSuccessAction, serviceErrorAction);} );                         
}  ;
```

Second operation:

```
if (OperationQueue!=null) {
    OperationQueue.WaitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (scrapbook.Picture.Url))
        PostScrap (scrapbook, serviceSuccessCallback, erviceErrorCallback);
    else
        errorAction (true);                                             
}
```

Comment: the recommended way of doing background processing in Xamarin.iOS is to use C#5 async/await capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.IOS (Monotouch) includes built-in support for .Net powerful Task infrastructure including C# 5.0 async/await support. Personally I wouldn't bother with NSOperationQueue for stuff like this. I've included a sample below. That invokes a webservice which responds with a string url to the upload.

```cs
public async Task<string> UploadImageData(byte[] imageData)
{
  var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

  using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
  {
    var content = new ByteArrayContent(imageData);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/postImage"), content);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: I got the solution,It was bcoz of I was using Async Rest service call,so that it was using the NsOperationQueue and It is making operation count zero when as we are using async call.So I have to make it sync so that it will not make operation count zero and it will wait.